# Trouble catching TCP traffic on port 23 - C#

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, tcp, telnet

I have a 'honeypot' that I am developing in C# that listens on a series of ports (user inputted). It is a large project/windows service that functions as expected for almost any port entered and will not listen on ports that currently have something listening already. The problem is that when I test the service using telnet or netcat, opening a connection on port 23 is not caught by my service and therefore establishes the connection.

I open the ports in the firewall by doing the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ports.Length; i++)
        {
            string arg = "advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"PeepHole Open" + "\" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=" + ports[i];
            string arg1 = "advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"PeepHole Open" + "\" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=" + ports[i];

            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", arg);
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo1 = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", arg1);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo1.UseShellExecute = false;

            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            procStartInfo1.CreateNoWindow = true;

            Process.Start(procStartInfo1);
            Process.Start(procStartInfo);

        }
```

And I start the listeners by:

```
 IPEndPoint Ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), current_port);
 //TcpListener tempListener = new TcpListener(hostIP, current_port);
 TcpListener tempListener = new TcpListener(Ep);
 TCP_Listener listen = new TCP_Listener();   //my defined tcplistener struct
 listen.listener = tempListener;             //set the Listener's TcpListener field
 listen.port = current_port;                 //set the Listener's Port field                                 
 listen.listener.Start();                    //start this particular TcpListener
 tcp_listener_list.Add(listen);              //add the struct to the list of Listeners
```

And accept the TCP connection by:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tcp_listener_list.Count - 1; i++)
 {
     if (tcp_listener_list[i].listener.Pending())
     {
         TcpClient client = tcp_listener_list[i].listener.AcceptTcpClient();
         int clientPort = tcp_listener_list[i].port;
         IPEndPoint ep = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LogTCP, new object[] { client, clientPort, ep });
      }
  }
```

And in LogTCP I close the connection by (where client is a TcpClient object):

```
 NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream(); 
 networkStream.Close();
 client.Close(); //close the connection, all the data is gleaned from the attacker already
```

Now the problem is that when I run telnet or netcat to test the closing and logging of the port, my code is never executed and the connection is established because the port is opened; the TCP connection never is .Pending() and if I remove that, the issue is persistent. Also, I have the same issue if I set up the listeners to use IPAddress.Any and if I reconfigure my accept method to AcceptSocket with or without the .Pending() if statement. Does windows treat certain ports differently on a low level with certain programs?

I am running a windows service from Windows 8.1 and sending TCP connections through telnet on putty (on the machine that the service is installed on) and telnet and netcat on a Linux VM. Both Telnet Client and Telnet Server are disabled on the 'host' machine.

I have tried many different variations of closing the sockets and connections that I found during my researching.

client.Client.Close() produces an ObjectDisposedException
client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both) makes all previously 'working' ports hang connections with CLOSE_WAIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key here, is you mention as an aside that you have created **your own struct**. Structs are very tricky. You might think that the below code will end up with a TCP_Listener instance that has your tempListener and current_port. But if you set a breakpoint you'll probably notice otherwise. Every modification you do on a struct actually returns a brand new struct, so you can't assign fields one at a time like you do with a class.

```
TCP_Listener listen = new TCP_Listener();   //my defined tcplistener struct
listen.listener = tempListener;             //set the Listener's TcpListener field
listen.port = current_port;                 //set the Listener's Port field                                 
listen.listener.Start();
```

I would recommend, rather than a struct, you use a class. Or you initialize your struct as new TCP_Listener(tempListener, current_port), then Start it.

That is at least part of your problem. Once you fix that, let us know if it's still not working and we can look at the next issue.

Comment: Actually, as I look at it, I'm surprised you're not getting a NullReferenceException. But the way you're assigning the struct does not seem correct. Is it really a struct?

Comment: This works for me. I guess I've been getting lucky with the other ports and port 23 uncovered this unexpected result. I ended up creating a simple class to replace the struct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Pending` is never needed. Just continually accept on all listeners. Start one task per listener to do that:

```
while (true) {
 ProcessConnectionAsync(await listener.AcceptAsync());
}
```

Something like this.

And here is an off-by-one bug: `tcp_listener_list.Count - 1`. But that bug goes away when you do it as explained above.

Regarding closing, why not just `client.Dispose();`? This is the normal way to do resource management in .NET. Nothing else is required.

Comment: Good catch. I changed it to a foreach loop that I have almost everywhere else and also removed the Pending() call. I guess I just got tunnel vision on this project. Thank you!